# Parameters of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

It was given to me to determine the number of parameters of a matrix 4x5 matrix with rank 4.

Honestly, i am not sure if this question makes sense. Anyway, i think it can vary between 4 and 14. 4 is the number of parameters if it would reduce by row echelon. \begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c & d & e\\ 
 & f & g & h &i \\ 
 &  & j & k & l\\ 
 &  &  & m & n
\end{bmatrix}

14 is the maximum number that the matrix allow in order to still be rank 4 (To see the confusion, i think we could exclude for example l subtracting using $L_{3} \space->\space L_{3} - l*L_{4}/n$, so the maximum number would reduce too?)

Now, so, what exactly is the answer for question like this? If not an interval?